# For centered Gaussian measures, is $E[\lVert X\rVert^2] \lesssim E[\lVert X\rVert ]^2$ true in infinite dimensions as well?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, gaussian

In the proof of Corollary 5.7 in the following link:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.05200.pdf

the author claims that $E[\lVert X\rVert^2] \lesssim E[\lVert X\rVert ]^2$ for the standard normal distribution on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I wonder if this result is still valid for cenetered Gaussian distributions on any infinite dimensional separable Banach space $V$ .

Moreover, the covariance for the measure is a symmetric nonnegative bilinear form on $V^*$. If the above inequality is still valid on $v$, how would the covariance affect it?

Could anyone please provide any information or reference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\si}{\sigma}$Yes, we have
\begin{equation*}
    E\|X\|^2\le c(E\|X\|)^2 \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
for
\begin{equation*}
    c:=1+2\pi
\end{equation*}
and any centered Gaussian random vector $X$ in any separable Banach space $V$.

This follows from the [Borell--Tsirelson--Ibragimov--Sudakov inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borell%E2%80%93TIS_inequality):
\begin{equation*}
    P(\|f\|_T\ge E\|f\|_T+u)\le\exp-\frac{u^2}{2\si_T^2}
\end{equation*}
for real $u\ge0$, where $(f_t)_{t\in T}$ is a centered Gaussian process, $\|f\|_T:=\sup_{t\in T}|f_t|$, and
\begin{equation*}
    \si_T:=\sqrt{\sup_{t\in T}Ef_t^2}. 
\end{equation*}

Indeed, let $T=B^*$, the unit ball in the dual $V^*$ to $V$, with $f_t:=t(X)$ for $t\in B^*$, so that $\|f\|_T=\|X\|$ and
\begin{equation*}
    \si_T=\si:=\sqrt{\sup_{t\in B^*}Et(X)^2}=\sqrt{\frac\pi2\,\sup_{t\in B^*}(E|t(X)|)^2}
    \le\sqrt{\frac\pi2}\,E\|X\|. \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}
So, for real $u\ge0$,
\begin{equation*}
    P(\|X\|\ge E\|X\|+u)\le\exp-\frac{u^2}{2\si^2}. 
\end{equation*}
(More immediately, the latter inequality is inequality (4.4) in [Ledoux's book](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BFb0095676.pdf).)

So,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    E\|X\|^2&=E\int_0^\infty 2w\,dw\,1(\|X\|\ge w) \\ 
    &=\int_0^\infty 2w\,dw\,P(\|X\|\ge w) \\ 
    &\le\int_0^{E\|X\|} 2w\,dw+\int_{E\|X\|}^\infty 2w\,dw\,\exp-\frac{(w-E\|X\|)^2}{2\si^2} \\ 
&=(E\|X\|)^2+2\si^2+\sqrt{2\pi}E\|X\|\si.  
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Now \eqref{1} follows from \eqref{2}. $\quad\Box$

Comment: @Isaac ; Yes, you can similarly consider the higher-order moments, by writing $E\|X\|^n=\int_0^\infty nw^{n-1}\,dw\,P(\|X\|\ge w)$.